# Supported browser in Botframework using Bing speech

Tags: botframework, bing-speech

I am using Bing for speech in botframework and when i deploy it the microphone is enabled only in Chrome and Edge, I read that its supported also in some other browser?

Comment: Have you opened other browser and tested?

Comment: Yes I tested with Firefox and safari as well but the mic button was disable?

Comment: Any error on their developer consoles? Can you add some code to show your chat implementation?

Comment: Error Message is "This browser does not support speech recognition".
I am using Bing speech options (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech)

Comment: I cannot found a documentation stating exactly which browser is supported or not, I'm still interested in the answers you will got!

Comment: If I open this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/)  with Explorer I get this line "To try out the demo with your own voice using a microphone, please change to a different browser with WebRTC support, for example a recent version of Microsoft Edge, Firefox or Chrome."  in speech recognition part so I assume this will work at least also in Firefox. The button "Start Recording" its visibile in firefox i tested it works but the mic of my chatbot is still disable. I coudnt find either a list of supported browser of Bing Speech.

Comment: @NicolasR Also is working in Opera. When I tried my bot in safari(using Windows 10 as OS)the mic is not showing but when i tried from my Iphone the mic is showing but i cant press on it ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, the error is triggered in this piece of the WebChat code (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/SpeechModule.ts#L117)

Then, I guess that there is a combination of things.

Based on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API#Browser_compatibility), the browser compatibility is:

[image]

As you can read, it seems that recognition on Firefox Desktop is not yet available.

Also, [this page](https://caniuse.com/#search=speech) shows speech (recognition and synthesis) support.

Then, not sure if the following will also apply to other browser, than Chrome, but maybe yes

[image]

Comment: I am using Bing Speech service it said that is supported in multiple browsers.(I tested in chrome, edge and opera is working, it should work also in firefox)

Comment: One thing is the underlying service that you are using for Bing Spech and a different thing is if the webchat speech recognition capability is enabled or not in the browser

Comment: @EzequielJadib I would say that the error comes from here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L65 as the OP is using Bing Speech (Cognitive Services), not the browser recognition.